# Will a stereo short render my bfcm fried?

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting, aftermarket-upgrade

I recently installed a aftermarket stereo into my2000 malibu and somewhere along the line it shorted and blew a couple fuses. The radio fuseand the interior fuse which was also the bfcm fuse,  i replaced the fuses but the wont start and slowly loses all power,,any suggestions??

Comment: You’re saying there’s drain on the battery? What do you mean it won’t start? Does it not crank? Start and stall? Crank no start?

Answer (score 0):

Something is shorting out clearly and creating a parasitic draw which drops starting power below threshold-check your installation as something is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for answering Andy, as soon as the short happened I took the head unit out and replaced all the blown fuses. I was thinking maybe because I waited till the next day to replace the fuses somehow the battery died. When I did try to start it it clicked repetitively and slowly lost power.

Comment: Run a mutimeter over every fuse-set meter to 200mv and see if any one of the fuses is dropping voltage-obviously, disable the interiror light first!